# Open some directories recursively in Dired

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to show a directory in Dired with some sub-directories opened recursively (as if I passed "R" option for them). Is it possible to do this in Emacs? Any ideas how to implement this easily in Elisp?

In windows explorer I would press '*' in folders window to open a directory recursively (of course only sub-directories are visible, not files). I want the same thing in Emacs, but that files are visible too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prefix `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` command (bound to `i` in *dired-mode*) with `C-u` to add recursive `-R` option for `ls` to insert directory recursively.

`C-u i` .. `R` .. `<RET>`

Answer (score 0):

Played with the idea a bit, and here's my solution, cleaner output and simpler usage. Put in your .emacs. Edit filter (man find) to suit your needs.

```
(defun find-dired-project (dir)
  (interactive "D")
  (find-dired dir "-not -path '*/.svn*' -not -path '*/.git*' -and -not -path '*.o' -and -type f"))
(global-set-key "\C-xd" 'find-dired-project)
```

Comment: You may want to use the `vc-directory-exclusion-list` and/or `completion-ignored-extensions` variables.